# Data normalization in SQL pivot query

Tags: sql-server

I have a following sql query which returns me index prices for 2 different indices.

```
select * 
from INDICEPRICEHISTORY 
PIVOT (MAX(PRICE) 
FOR TICKER IN 
([OMXH25],[UX])
) 
as Pricelist 
ORDER BY EOD DESC;
```

Query returns:

```
EOD         OMXH25   UX
2015-10-10  3157.20  843.48
2015-10-09  3157.20  843.48
2015-10-08  3138.35  837.37
2015-10-07  3138.47  835.43
```

Is there any way to normalize this data in sql query for some base point, for example 2015-10-07 to be 100 points and other values are related to that. Mockup below:

```
EOD         OMXH25       UX
2015-10-10  100.5967876  100.9635756
2015-10-09  100.5967876  100.9635756
2015-10-08  99.99617648  100.2322157
2015-10-07  100          100
```

Idea is to make these two (or more) columns comparable in a line chart.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible in SQL? I'm using MSSQL 2014.

Thank you!

Comment: You select top 1 from result. Then cross join result on that top1 and calc r.value*100/t.value(r result, t top 1)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
;with r as(your current query),
      t as(select top 1 * from r order by eod)
select r.eod, 
       r.omxh25 * 100 / t.omxh25 as omxh25,
       r.ux * 100 / t.ux as ux
from r
cross join t
```